# Internet Explorer 11 downloads a URL unexpectedly

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I am trying to diagnose an issue, where one single user out of many, finds that IE11 downloads an EXE

That EXE is mentioned in the URL, lets say:  `http://my.site/path/this.EXE`

For all other users, an HTML page is returned as you would expect, otherwise I would suspect that MIME-type handling was broken on the server, but since this only occurs to one user, presumably the fault is with the config of this one instance of IE?

Searching for an explanation is tricky, as 99% of people on the internet appear to have the exact opposite problem!

Comment: Why would you expect http://my.site/path/this.EXE to display a HTML page?

Comment: A: because that is what the EXE is supposed to do - similar to a CGI process.
B: Because that is what it does for every other user.

Comment: In this case, I think the correct header of the server response should be `text/html`, but the user got the wrong MIME type from the server response, such as `application/...`. You can try to reset the IE configuration. `IE tools` -> Internet Options -> Advanced tab -> Reset....

Comment: @XudongPeng  I agree that it looks like a mime-type issue, but I don't see what IE11 would do to affect the mime-type that the server returns? It's a managed installation, so a reset-to-factory-defaults probably isn't possible, and probably isn't wise, so was hoping for a specific setting to check/correct